# Sending mail in PHP with remote mail server and reverse DNS lookup

Tags: php, email, ssl, remote-server, spam

I am sending mail in PHP, but I use a remote mail server.

I have three questions:

1) In my PHP mail code, should I use the server settings for the local mail server or the remote mail server and is there a difference?

2) If I use the remote mail server, won't the mailserver domain IP address not match the real domain's IP Address (potentially going to Spam folders)?

The problem I am having might be specific to my host, mail server, version, or mail plugin.

I am trying to use a plugin called Swiftmailer to send mail through my local mail server, which works on port 25 with no SSL. When I switch the port to 465 (per my host's recommendation) and change it to SSL, I get a refused connection. (I believe this is because I don't have SSL added to this server yet)

3) Does SSL really matter? Should I just use port 25 without SSL and save myself the trouble? (I care about security, not server requirements)

Comment: 1. Remote. 3. Depends if your server require it

Comment: 2. search for "spf txt record", DNS reverse lookup may be still helpful, but it's pretty much "old way".